# Loop won't end despite the use of a sentinel value

Tags: java

This is an example straight out of my text book, and I can't get it to end the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play {

    System.out.println("Enter scores for all students.");
    System.out.println("Enter a negative number after");
    System.out.println("you have entered all the scores.");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double max = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double min = max;
    double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
    while(next >= 0)
    {
        if(next > max)
            max = next;
        else if (next < min)
            min = next;
        next = keyboard.nextDouble();

    }
    System.out.println("The highest score is " + max);
    System.out.println("The lowest score is " + min);
}
```

Comment: what input are you giving the program?

Comment: @Breedly - it worked for me, after I added a main() method.

Comment: Capturing two doubles before the loop is a bad idea. "double next = keyboard.nextDouble(); min = max = next;" is better. Also, this code doesn't compile as written. Are you missing something?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code? If not that at least put a couple of sysouts inside the while and check what values the variables are holding.

Comment: I can't find the problem. In your case, you might want to post the entire class.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the demo for you (see below).

He was using while when he should use do while.

The demo states that you use a negative number to exit the loop (below zero).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Student score entry demo:");
    System.out.println("NB: Enter a negative number to finish.\n");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double max = -1;
    double min = max;
    double score;
    do {
      System.out.println("Enter student score: ");
      score = keyboard.nextDouble();
      if (score > max) {
        max = score;
      } else if (min < 0 || score < min && score >= 0) {
        min = score;
      }
    } while (score >= 0);
    // Output results
    System.out.println("The highest score was: " + max);
    System.out.println("The lowest score was: " + min);
  }
```

**Output:**

Student score entry demo:

NB: Enter a negative number after you have entered all the scores to finish.

Enter student score:
22

Enter student score:
33

Enter student score:
44

Enter student score:
55

Enter student score:
11

Enter student score: 
-3

The highest score was: 55.0 
The lowest score was: 11.0

Comment: every do-while can be written as a while and vice-versa. I don't understand how this made the difference.

Comment: That helps a lot, but can you explain your logic behind setting max = -1?

Comment: @Sagar V: yes, but making it a do while means you don't need to have the additional pre-loop read which is ugly.

Comment: @Breedly -1 is just a sentinel value, I have no strong reason for having started at -1; I'm using it to check if min had been set now that the pre-loop read has been removed. TBH I prefer the use of Double.MIN/MAX as used in Hila's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition says `next >= 0`, it should be `next > 0`. Are you supposed to enter a negative value to finish entering values?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 0.02$.
The logic is explained in the comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Print instructions
System.out.println("Enter scores for all students.");
System.out.println("Enter a negative number after");
System.out.println("you have entered all the scores.");

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

// Init min and max
// Any grade will be lower than the current min grade 
// (which is the higest possible value a double can hold),
// and higher than the current max grade.
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

// Read first grade. Allow the user to terminate the loop
// without entering grades
double next = keyboard.nextDouble();
while(next >= 0)
{
    if(next > max)
        max = next;

    // Removed else-if. This ensures the first grade is
    // initialized correctly
    if (next < min)
        min = next;
    next = keyboard.nextDouble();

}

// Make sure we got some grades
if (max == Double.MIN_VALUE && min == Double.MAX_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("No scores entered. Your students are lazy.");
} else {
    System.out.println("The highest score is " + max);
    System.out.println("The lowest score is " + min);
}
```

}

Try to enter -1 as the only grade, and a list of grades followed by -1, see what you get.

Comment: I like the use of Double.MIN/MAX but I think removing the pre-loop read would be better.

Comment: @Syntax I wanted to allow the user to be able to terminate the loop without entering any grades. It really depends on how you want your application to behave, and if you do want to allow this, well - in that case it's a matter of style.